# Как правильно установить ловушку (windows hook) из DLL библиотеки?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, hook

Я изучаю тему "Системные ловушки", сейчас пытаюсь реализовать одну из самых простых ловушек, которая перехватывает сообщения мыши.
Функция `MouseHook`, которая должна обрабатывать сообщения мыши, а именно получать координаты и записывать их в файл (тут нет практической цели, просто чтобы продемонстрировать работу) реализована в DLL-библиотеке.
Программа не заработала.
Дело в том, что `SetWindowsHook`, которая принимает в качестве параметров, в том числе, дескриптор библиотеки и указатель на функцию не работает, как выяснилось, потому что `GetProcAddress` возвращает нулевой указатель на функцию. И не смотря ни на что продолжает возвращать.
 Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своими догадками, почему это может быть так.
Вот несколько упрощенный вариант кода:

```
//Функция в DLL
extern  "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE || wParam == WM_NCMOUSEMOVE)
    {
        PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
        f << "X: " << p->pt.x << "Y: " << p->pt.y << std::endl;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

---

```
// Главная функция приложения
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    hLib = LoadLibrary(DLL_MOUSE_HOOK_LOCATION);
    if (hLib)
    {
        pMouseHook = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hLib, "MouseHook");
        hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, pMouseHook, hLib, NULL);
        if (InitApplication(hInst, nCmdShow))
        {
            while (GetMessage(&msg, (HWND)(NULL), 0, 0))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
            return 0;
        }
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);
    }
    FreeLibrary(hLib);
    return 0;
}
```

Я рассматривал вариант, в котором хук устанавливается функцией DLL-библиотеки, допустим `EnableMouseHook`, адрес которой можно корректно получить, а `MouseHook` вообще остается внутренней функцией библиотеки. Адрес получается, но программа по прежнему не работает и я не уверен, что так вообще правильно. Обидно, на самом деле.

(обновлено)

Проблема с нулевым указателем была решена путем замены `GetProcAddress(hLib, "MouseHook")` на `GetProcAddress(hLib, "_MouseHook@12")`. Как оказалось, это нюанс экспорта функций с приставкой `__stdcall` из DLL. Второй параметр в `GetProcAddress` нужно передавть в виде 
`"_<Имя_функции>@<Сумарный_размер_всех_параметров>"`.
На ловушку, по прежнему, 0 реакции.

(обновлено)

Спустя дни, оказалось.. Что ошибка была в другом месте программы. Так что код выше рабочий.

П.С. Надеюсь, пример будет кому-то полезен.

Comment: `GetProcAddress возвращает нулевой указатель` - нужно использовать`GetLastError` и смотреть какой код ошибки она вернёт.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно заменить `GetProcAddress(hLib, "MouseHook")` на `GetProcAddress(hLib, "_MouseHook@12")`. Это нюанс экспорта функций с приставкой `__stdcall` из DLL. Второй параметр в `GetProcAddress` нужно передавть в виде `"_<Имя_функции>@<Сумарный_размер_всех_параметров>"`, тогда код заработет.